# $p$-group as product of two normal cyclic subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The quaternion group of order 8 is an example of a non-abelian $p$-group which is product of two cyclic normal subgroups.

Are there more examples? what happens for $p$ odd - are there such examples?

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind: Groups of order $p$ or order $p^2$ for a prime $p$ are always abelian. So you should search at least size $p^3$ for examples...

Comment: There are nonabelian groups of order $p^3$ for all primes $p$ that are products of two normal cyclic subgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$G = \langle x,y \mid x^{p^k}=y^p=1, y^{-1}xy=x^{1+p^{k-1}} \rangle$$

where $k \ge 2$, and $k \ge 3$ if $p=2$. (When $p=k=2$, you need to replace the relation $y^2=1$ by $y^2=x^2$ to get the quaternion group.)

Then $G$ is nonabelian of order $p^{k+1}$ and is the product of the normal cyclic subgroups $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle xy \rangle$ of order $p^k$.